# Store GraphQL errors as String

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, graphql, apollo

I have a login form. When the submit button is hit, I check via the GraphQL backend if email and password are correct. If yes, a token is returned and stored in local storage.  At times, there are **errors** like:

**'Incorrect Password' or 'User Doesn't Exist'.**

Is there any way to **store these errors as strings** so I can display them later using conditional rendering?

This is how my mutation looks like:

```
function submitForm(LoginMutation: any) {
    const { email, password } = state;
    if(email && password){
      LoginMutation({
        variables: {
            email: email,
            password: password,
        },
    }).then(({ data }: any) => {
      localStorage.setItem('token', data.loginEmail.accessToken);
    })
    .catch(console.log)
    }
  }
```

and I am using it like this in my return

```
 return (
      <Mutation mutation={LoginMutation}>
        {(LoginMutation: any) => (
        ....)}>
       </Mutation>
)
```

For now, I am just displaying a single error on the basis of whether the token exists or not but I want to make my error specific to the GraphQL errors.

```
function ShowError(){
  if (!localStorage.getItem('token'))
  {
    console.log('Login Not Successful');
    return <Typography color='primary'>Login Not Successful</Typography>

  }
}
```

**Edit:**

Example Error:

```
[Log] Error: GraphQL error: Key (email)=(c@c.com) already exists.
```

I tried this but it never logs anything:

````
.then(({data, errors}:any) => {
        if (errors && errors.length) {
          console.log('Errors', errors);
          setErrorMessage(errors[0].message);
          console.log('Whats the error', errors[0].message)
        } else {
          console.log('ID: ', data.createUser.id);
        }
      })
    ```
The backend isn't made by me
````

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you have a few things set up, but, assuming you have access to `state` in your `ShowError` function:

When using GraphQL, errors can happen in 2 ways:
1. A network error, which will be caught in the `.catch`. To handle this, in your `catch` you can store the error message in state, and then access it from `ShowError`:

```js
...
.catch(err => {
  setState({errorMessage: err.message});
});
```

2. As a result of a bad query, which generally returns a successful response with an `errors` array. To handle this case, you can add an error check in your `.then`:

```js
...
.then(({data, errors}) => {
  if (errors && errors.length) {
    setState({errorMessage: errors[0].message});
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem('token', data.loginEmail.accessToken);
  }
});
```

Comment: Could you please see the updated qs? I tried 2. but it doesn't work for me. Nothing is logged

Comment: If you don’t control the backend, it’s possible they return the error as a network error. Did you try adding a lot in the catch? Where are you seeing the log you added ( the example error)?

Comment: *adding a log, not adding a lot